# Whoops Something went wrong? Como saber que tipo de error se ha generado

Tags: laravel

una pregunta, al estar utilizando Laravel, en muchos momentos me sale este mensaje, Mi pregunta es como puedo averguar algo mas expliativo. Gracias.

Comment: En el log de Laravel, revisa la documentación.

Comment: Laravel crea un log con los errores que se producen en <tu-proyecto>/storage/logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la raíz de tu proyecto laravel debe haber un archivo .env es un archivo oculto por lo que si no tienes activada la opción para ver archivos ocultos debes activarla, si luego de activar esa opción aun no encuentras dicho archivo entonces agrégalo.

En ese archivo puedes configurar tu proyecto definiendo variables globales.

Debes establecer `APP_DEBUG=true` en ese archivo.

---

> Cuando no se detecta una excepción y la variable de entorno `APP_DEBUG`
>   es `true`, la página de depuración mostrará todas las variables de
>   entorno y su contenido.

[Más detalles](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration)

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Saludos.